# Unable to login or reset password

Tags: authentication, heroku

I have and account with heroku but the email used to log into the account has been deleted sometime ago.  I am receiving an "There was a problem with your login" when I try to log in.  I can't reset the password as I can't receive the email.  Any suggestions on how I can log in to that account?

Comment: [Heroku help](https://help.heroku.com/7IDU8QZZ/what-should-i-do-if-i-m-locked-out-of-my-heroku-account): "Heroku cannot help you obtain access to your Heroku account if you do not have access to the email address for your account. Please contact your IT department or email provider if you have lost access to your email address." In other words, you probably no longer have an account with Heroku.

Comment: I still have the sites hosted with Heroku under that email address it was a company email address that no longer exists.  How can I access the sites that were hosted under that email account?

Comment: I meant, the account still exists, but you don't have it, according to their policy. There does not seem to be a way to log into that account unless you either find the password or regain access to that email account. If the domain of your old email is currently unowned, you could try to register the domain to a mail server under your control and recreate your email, I suppose.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku support.